# drake gurobi cannot handle quadratic constraint

Tags: drake

I am currently working to implement a simple quadratic constraint on an optimization problem. [Gurobi's website](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_addqconstr.html) says that quadratic constraints can be implemented.
Does drake not have an interface with this constraint using Gurobi?

The code is as follows.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "drake/solvers/mathematical_program.h"
#include "drake/solvers/solve.h"
#include "drake/solvers/gurobi_solver.h"
#include "drake/solvers/scs_solver.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace drake;

int main(){
    solvers::MathematicalProgram prog; 

    // Instantiate the decision variables
    solvers::VectorXDecisionVariable x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, "x");

    // Define constraints 
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      prog.AddConstraint(x[i]*x[i] <= 2); //Replacing this with a linear constraint 
                                          //such as prog.AddLinearConstraint(-5 <= x[i] && x[i] <= 5); 
                                          //will work
    }

    // Define the cost
    MatrixXd Q(2,2);
    Q << 2, 1,
         1, 4;
    VectorXd b(2);
    b << 0, 3;
    double c = 1.0;
    prog.AddQuadraticCost(Q, b, c, x);

    solvers::GurobiSolver solver;
    cout << "Gurobi available? " << solver.is_enabled() << endl;

    auto result = solver.Solve(prog);
    cout << "Is optimization successful?" << result.is_success() << endl;
    cout << "Optimal x: " << result.GetSolution().transpose() << endl;
    cout << "solver is: " << result.get_solver_id().name() << endl;
    cout << "computation time is: " << result.get_solver_details<solvers::GurobiSolver>().optimizer_time;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drake currently (intentionally) doesn't support the quadratic constraint. For better solver performance, I would recommend to reformulate the optimization problem without quadratic constraint, but with second-order cone constraints.

First for a quadratic constraint

```
xᵀx <= a²
```

This can be regarded as a Lorentz cone constraint

```
(y, x) is in the Lorentz cone
y = a
```

In Drake, you could add this constraint as

```cpp
prog.AddLorentzConeConstraint((drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Expression>(x.rows() + 1) << a, x).finished());
```

For the more general quadratic constraint `0.5xᵀQx + bᵀx + c<=0`, we also provide [AddQuadraticAsRotatedLorentzConeConstraint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a7b12192393b9a53b4fd484ede7d52381) which imposes a rotated Lorentz cone constraint.

```cc
prog.AddQuadraticAsRotatedLorentzConeConstraint(Q, b, c, x);
```

For the quadratic cost

```
min 0.5xᵀQx + bᵀx + c
```

you could also reformulate it as a linear cost with a rotated Lorentz cone constraint

```
min z
z >= 0.5xᵀQx + bᵀx + c
```

In Drake, the code is

```
z = prog.NewContinuousVariables<1>()(0);
prog.AddLinearCost(z);
prog.AddRotatedLorentzConeConstraint(symbolic::Expression(z), symbolic::Expression(1), 0.5 * x.dot(Q * x) + b.dot(x) + c);
```

The reason why we would prefer Lorentz cone constraint, instead of a quadratic-constrained-quadratic-program (QCQP), is that with Lorentz cone constraint, you end up with a second-order conic optimization problem (SOCP), this optimization problem has a lot of nice features, in terms of its dual form. You could read the paper Alizadeh's [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.616.7497&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for more details. And Mosek also recommends SOCP over QCQP https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/rmosek/prob-def-quadratic.html#a-recommendation

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation. I'll make sure to read your suggested paper as well.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the (as-of-yet unimplemented) feature request at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/6341 is what you're looking for?